# What's the constraint kinds syntax for GHC 7.4.1?

Tags: haskell, typeclass, constraint-kinds

I'm getting an error that `Constraint` is not in scope, when I try to write a simple example,

```
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances,
            MultiParamTypeClasses,
            KindSignatures,
            Rank2Types,
            ConstraintKinds,
            FlexibleInstances,
            OverlappingInstances,
            TypeFamilies #-}

type family A a :: Constraint
```

The error is,

```
> ghci test.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( test.hs, interpreted )

test.hs:10:20: Not in scope: type constructor or class `Constraint'
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

Constraint synonyms seem to work as expected,

```
type ShowOrd a = (Ord a, Show a)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Your error appears to be caused by `Constraint` being, unsurprisingly, not in scope. You'll want to import it from `GHC.Prim` or [from `GHC.Exts`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/4.5.0.0/doc/html/GHC-Exts.html#g:12).

It seems a bit odd that enabling `ConstraintKinds` doesn't bring it into scope automatically, as it does in a 7.3.2 snapshot build I had lying around, but there you go.

Comment: Is there an official place to import it from instead of GHC.Prim. One that might allow it to work on other compilers that support those extensions.